# Making dlls in qt

Tags: c++, dll, qt4

Where can i get a tutorial on making dlls in qt?.I have been reading the latest docs on version 4.7 and i haven't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the qmake variable [`TEMPLATE`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html#template)..

Similarly from the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-common-projects.html#library),

`dll` option will output you the dll instead of an exe.